# my .Net app gets load error for NuGet package HDF5DotNet.DLL x86 on Windows 10 virtualization by VirtualBox or VMware on ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, hdf5, hdf5dotnet

My .NET windows forms app gets error (below) when it tries to call a function in the HDF5dotNet.DLL NuGet package.

My app runs on Windows 10, which runs in a 64bit Oracle VirtualBox (ie. virtual machine) that was spun up by ubuntu linux on an actual physical machine.

UPDATE: I get same error using VMware instead of VirtualBox.
Also, same exact copy of my app calls HDF5dotNet with no error when I run on boot Windows native (instead of ubuntu).

However, when project is copied as-is to a physical windows 10 machine, it runs ok and loads and runs a function in the HDF5dotNet.DLL NuGet package ok.

I've tried both x64 and x86 versions of the HDF5.NET NuGet package.  Same problem.

[image]

ERROR DETAILS

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x8007007E   Message=Could
>   not load file or assembly 'HDF5DotNet.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The specified module could not be found.
>   Source=2_HDF5_WindowsFormsApp1   StackTrace:    at
>   HDF5_Class.read_color_table(String color_table_pathname, Double[,]&
>   color_table_dataset) in
>   C:\PRIMARY\WORK\2_HDF5_WindowsFormsApp1\SOURCE\HDF5_file.cs:line 1047 
>   at _2_HDF5_WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in C:\PRIMARY\WORK\2_HDF5_WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 27    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: http://hdf5.net The official guide does not refer to the NuGet packages, so I don't think you are on the right track.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?